# Restore Purchase Functionality doesn't work well in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am having an app in which I have 5 Non Consumable In App Purchases.

I am using the following code for Restore In App Purchase.

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{

    //NSLog(@"into method1");
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    }

    // [customSpinner hide:YES];

    if (queue.transactions.count==0)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FameFace" message:@"It seems you have not buy this Package" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }

    else
    {

        NSLog(@"Data available");


       NSString *isInApp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Package"];

        if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack1"])
        {

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"])
            {
                // app already launched
                NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
            }
            else
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"];
                NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                requestText= @"Animal";
                [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                [self getdata];
            }




        }

        else if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack2"])
        {

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"])
            {
                // app already launched
                NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
            }
            else
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"];
                NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                requestText= @"Celebrity";
                [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                [self getdata];
            }

        }

        else if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack3"])
        {
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"])
            {
                // app already launched
                NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
            }
            else
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"];
                NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                requestText= @"Nature";
                [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                [self getdata];
            }


        }
}
```

Below is the code when there is successful transaction.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //[self downloadFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iphonedevnation.com/tutorials/ForestGreen.mp3"]];
                // flgCheck = 1;
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
   NSString *isInApp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Package"];
 if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack1"])
                {
                    //by manthan...7th  may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Animal";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }

                }

                else if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack2"])
                {

                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Celebrity";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }

                }

                else if ([isInApp isEqualToString:@"Pack3"])
                {
                    //by manthan... 7th may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Nature";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }
                }
```

This is working fine.

What I am doing is that I am inserting some images in my DB when user Purchases a package from In App Purchase.

But as the Product is Non Consumable, If the user deletes the app and trying to Restore Images, My DB doesn't get updated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks...

**Edited**

I put my code in the method below when user try to restore purchase.

As I have a single restore button and on pressing that button, user will have previously purchased packages that may be 2,3 or 4(any of the 5 packages that user has purchased once as these are non consumable products).

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                NSString *pk = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Package"];

                if ([pk isEqualToString:@"Pack1"])
                {
                    //by manthan...7th  may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Animal";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }

                }

                else if ([pk isEqualToString:@"Pack2"])
                {
                    //by manthan... 7th may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Celebrity";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }

                }

                else if ([pk isEqualToString:@"Pack3"])
                {
                    //by manthan... 7th may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Nature";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }
                }
```

when there is only one single purchase I can simply update my DB in **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored**.

But when i have multiple non consumable products what should i do?

**edited**

```
 if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack1"])
                {
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp1Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Animal";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }
                }


                else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack2"])
                {
                    //by manthan... 7th may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp2Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Celebrity";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }

                }

                else if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Pack3"])
                {
                    //by manthan... 7th may
                    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"])
                    {
                        // app already launched
                        NSLog(@"Launching secondtime");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedp3Once"];
                        NSLog(@"Launching first time");
                        requestText= @"Nature";
                        [self MakeQueryForUpdate];
                        [self getdata];
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the case of `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` in the `updatedTransactions` method for doing this.

When restoring this case will be executed.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions)
   {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                //do your database stuff
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

---

#### Reference

> **Payment Transaction States**
>
> The state of a transaction.

```
enum { SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing,
SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased, SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed,
SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored };

typedef NSInteger SKPaymentTransactionState;
```

> ***Constants***
>
> **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing**
>
> ```
> The transaction is being processed by the App Store.
> ```
>
> **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased**
>
> ```
> The App Store successfully processed payment. Your application should provide the content the user purchased.
> ```
>
> **SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed**
>
> ```
> The transaction failed. Check the error property to determine what happened.
> ```
>
> **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored**
>
> ```
> This transaction restores content previously purchased by the user. Read the originalTransaction property to obtain information about the original purchase.
>
> Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
>
> Declared in SKPaymentTransaction.h.
> ```

Check [SKPaymentTransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionState) for more

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to ask you that apple provide this functionality in case if the user deletes the app and just restores, the previously contained features purchased with in app do come. So do i need to fire a query when user presses the restore button?

Comment: If user presses the Restore button the previously purchased items will be there without any cost. But you need to do other tasks (Database adding of purchased items) by your own, else when you kill the app the state will be again reset to initial state. When you press the restore button for purchased items the `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` case will executed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. As you said i shifted my code to the method **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** As you can see from my above code when pressing the restore button it is not going into my loop so the DB doesn't get updated when i try to restore purchase after shifting the code to the method you mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please give me any answer on this? In my method **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored**, how to identify which package user has bought? I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @ManthanPatel: you can get the product identifier using `transaction.payment.productIdentifier`

Comment: Yes, I can get my Product Ids via this but how to get Only Purchased Product Ids? So that I can use them in the method **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** and my DB gets updated. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: @ManthanPatel: I didn't understand your question well. If the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored case is hit ? Why don't you take the product Id using `transaction.payment.productIdentifier ` and update the db ?

Comment: i m putting the code above and please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @ManthanPatel: second code (second edit) looks good, what happened when you added that ?

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.I did that as you said but it doesn't go into my loop. If I simply put the DB code in **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored**. My DB gets updated but when i put that into the edited code shown above in the loop It doesn't because It doesn't identify which product has been purchased.so  What Should i do? Is there any way I can get the list of only purchased Products Product Id? If i can get that I can do the code in **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** method. Any idea?

Comment: :Thanks so much for your help. Second edited code was perfect. The Product id was having error. Thanks.